# Context-free grammar for a language

Tags: compiler-construction, language-design, computation-theory

I have a problem with the following language:

[image]

I must write a context-free grammar:

[image]

which describes it. I have already done a few exercises but this one is really hard for me.I'm sitting around for hours without an useful approach. It wouldn't be a problem to write a grammar without the part  *N0: (m=l) v (l = 2n)* . But i don't how to get this one done. I would be very thankful for any advice.

Comment: You might want to also post this to http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/ if you haven't already.

Comment: @Matthew: cstheory is for research-level questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about the syntax for G2 but the following CFG works:

```
S = S1 | S2

S1 = S11 C
S11 = <empty> | a S11 b
C = <empty> | c C

S2 = aa S2 c | B
B = <empty> | b B
```

Comment: Sincerly it does not work, but thank you anyway, maybe i can make it work with a few changes. An example which does not work would be: S = S2; S2 = a S2 cc with S2 = B = <empty>. That would create "acc" which is not allowed.